# "on_member_join" (message.timestamp error)

Tags: python, discord.py

CODE:

```
from termcolor import colored

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
server = member.server
print("[" + (colored("{}".format(message.timestamp), 'white')) + "]" + colored("[{0}] {1} joined the Server!".format(server, member), 'green'))
```

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: What is the `message`?

Comment: "{}".format(message.timestamp)

Comment: you haven't defined `message`

Comment: ho I define message if it member defined and its not possible define 2 things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Member` joining a server isn't associated with any `Message`, so the event doesn't send a `message` argument.  You can get the `datetime` a `Member` joined a `Server` with [`Member.joined_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.joined_at) instead.

Comment: but when the member leaves the server, it shows when he joined, not when he lefted

Comment: I think your only choice there is use the current time when you receive the event.  There is not way to use `Message.timestamp`, because no `Message` is being sent for these events.

Comment: NameError: name 'Message' is not defined